# ATmega32U4 I/O Pin Alternate Functions

Tags: spi, atmega, microprocessor, atmega32u4

I am using an ATmega32U4 as a master with 2 slave ADCs (AD7739), ADC1 and ADC2. The two ADCs are identical. The SS, SCLK, MOSI, and MISO for ADC1 correspond to ports PORTB0,1,2, and 3 respectively, according to their SPI alternate functions described in the datasheet.

Now, when I add ADC2, I want to collect its output data. Can I have another distinct set of SS, SCLK, MOSI, and MISO on the general I/O ports of PORTB7, PORTB6, PORTC7, and PORTC6 respectively?

In other words, do the ports PORTB7, PORTB6, PORTC7, and PORTC6 also have the alternate functionality to behave as SS, SCLK, MOSI, or MISO?

Comment: Why do you think they can, and why do you think they can't? What do those functions mean, anyway? Do you know how SPI works and for example what SS does? And why a certain pin is labelled with SS as an alternate function? These questions are to determine your level of knowledge

Comment: @user253751 I suspect they can because MISO and MOSI are just I/O signals, so there doesn't seem to be any reason why a given I/O could not be used. SCLK is just a pulse train, so again, there doesn't seem to be any reason why any given I/O wouldn't work. I suspect they can't because in the datasheet, PORTB0,1,2,3 are explicitly specified as having that ability, while no other I/O port has this specification. To answer your questions, I have a conceptual understanding of SPI mechanics, but I do not why a certain pin would have specifically SS, SCLK, MISO, or MOSI as an alternate function.

Comment: Why do you need another set of full SPI pins? In general, you would use the same clock and data pins, and then separate chip select pins. Why is this not possible?

Comment: @Justme yes, this would be ideal. The board I am using was modified to add this extra ADC, and it is simply wired the way described in the question.

Comment: @Zachary Great, just make sure that two or more ADCs can be connected together. Some SPI devices can keep the data output always active so they can't share the bus. But you don't mention which ADC is this so it may or may not be a solution.

Comment: @Justme Yes.. and for reference, they are two AD7739 ADCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a hardware mapping to `PORTC` and there is only one hardware SPI module in the ATmega32U4. If you look at Figure 17-1 in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) you can see the SPI module is quite complicated, and there isn't a mux to connect it to other pins. So, your two options are to use the chip select lines on your ADCs (if they have them) and read them sequentially with shared data and clock lines, or to bit-bang the SPI protocol on different ports. Even if you had two SPI modules, the first option would be more or less equivalent as the ATmega32U4 doesn't have a DMA handler.

Of course the *best* option, unless you absolutely can't change microcontroller, is to get a good modern microcontroller which will have more SPI modules, more mux options, be faster and more efficient, and probably cheaper. Something like the STM32 series or ATSAM series would be ideal, and will not constrain you to the out dated world of expensive 8-bit microcontrollers.

Comment: I see. Thanks @awjlogan. The board I am using is simply what I have inherited in my research group, so there is no changing connections/hardware. This rules out options 1 and 3. 

I am not familiar with the "bit-bang" method, so I will look into it. If you have the time, could you briefly explain how I would use this method to read MISO of the ADC2 via pin PORTC6?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, so I'll put another here. would the bit-banging method only be necessary to supply an SCLK signal to the ADC2? Assuming that I could successfully supply this SCLK, could I then read the ADC output on any given open I/O port, or is there only one MOSI and MISO hardware-supported pin (B2,3) on the board? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: "Bit-banging" is doing the transmission protocol by software, so you can use whatever pins you like. The obvious issue is that it is (much) slower and requires you to have a good knowledge of the protocol and timings.

Comment: Thanks, @awjlogan. Let's say that I am able to write working code that allows me to receive data from ADC2. Would ADC1 (hardware SPI) and ADC2 (software SPI) be able to transmit/receive their own data simultaneously? I understand that the software SPI would be consuming much larger processing power..

Comment: @Zachary - yes, that would be possible, they're on two separate interfaces so it would be down to your software to coordinate the process.